# Magento 2.4 - Two factor authentication

Tags: magento2.4, two-factor-authentication

I'm upgrading my development migration to 2.4.  I was surprised to see that 2FA was enabled.  Can this be turned off?

I have enough issues to deal with and prefer not to go through this learning curve.  I prefer not to be forced to add apps to my phone so that I may get into the admin.  I would prefer the ability to make the decision to add this at production time.

Answer (score 9):

You can disable the 2FA module with

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

This will let you login to admin normally until you have done your own risk assessments and set your security policy for Magento admin login.

For a more elegant solution the following module will let you disable and enable 2FA from the command line or admin

https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth

Answer (score 2):

you can **disable** using this command :

```
 bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
 bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, by adding a system configuration to Enable/Disable it. I made a module, you can download it with composer:

```
composer require wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa
```

Or check it at: https://github.com/wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth module and then run all commands for cache and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

> **Please disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth module**

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:c
```

> **OR**

> Into **Magento_root/app/etc/config.php** find **Magento_TwoFactorAuth** and put 1 to 0 like this then save the file and run php bin/magento s:up
> command.

```
'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => 0,
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

> Securing your Magento Admin account. Two-factor authentication (2FA)
> is now required for the Magento Admin. Admin users must first
> configure their 2FA before logging into the Admin through either the
> UI or a web API. 2FA is enabled by default and cannot be disabled.
> This extra step of authentication makes it harder for malicious users
> to log in to the Admin without authorization.

[source](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html)

Comment: How do you feel about this?