# How to disable Two factor Authentication module in Magento 2.4

Tags: command-line, magento2.4, two-factor-authentication

How can I disable the **Two-factor** **Authentication module** using **command-line** ?

Comment: just found the module with the help of `grep` command...this works `php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth` well....

Comment: please post this comment as answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.4 - Two factor authentication](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318674/magento-2-4-two-factor-authentication)

Answer (score 182, accepted):

please run below command in terminal Magento root path :

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth 
Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i would not recommend to force disable the module, rather use new module which extend the configuration so there should always be an option to control the configurations from admin panel.

Comment: @ZeeshanKhuwaja it's useful to disable this in development to avoid having to perform 2FA on your development machine when logging into admin. I wouldn't disable in production as it's a useful security feature.

Comment: Yes, this feature enabled by default is a pain for localhost installation. I would prefer to login without it and then enable this feature from the Admin panel.

Comment: For me, I needed to run "bin/magento setup:di:compile" also

Comment: or bin/magento module:disable MSP_TwoFactorAuth

Comment: for those that aren't able to get the above to work, add php in from of both commands. Further you can add sudo php and then the answer's command and it worked for me.

Comment: This is the result of running bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
The following modules have been disabled:
- Magento_TwoFactorAuth

Cache cleared successfully.
Generated classes cleared successfully. Please run the 'setup:di:compile' command to generate classes.
Info: Some modules might require static view files to be cleared. To do this, run 'module:disable' with the --clear-static-content option to clear them.

So the proper answer would be to run
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento setup:di:compile

Not 
bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: First, we need to disable the Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth module because the Magento_TwoFactorAuth module depends on the Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth module.

Answer (score 19):

Mark Shust created a [module](https://github.com/markshust/magento2-module-disabletwofactorauth) for this purpose which is developer-friendly while keeping secure defaults in place; ref [his comments about it](https://twitter.com/markshust/status/1293145668509478912?s=21)

Comment: Definitely the better option to use this module than to generally disable 2FA.

Comment: Thanks @benmarks, the module works really great except the part that it does not work on the REST APIs interface. Seems the patch only works on the admin area not on all areas.

Answer (score 15):

For magento 2.4.6 to disable Two Factor Authentication module

```
php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth,Magento_TwoFactorAuth}
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, by adding a system configuration to Enable/Disable it. I made a module, you can download it with composer:

```
composer require wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa
```

Or check it at: https://github.com/wolfsellers/module-enabledisabletfa

Comment: You have copied same answer to two questions, please do some changes at content to make two answers are  different

Answer (score 2):

It would help

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

Answer (score 1):

From Magento 2.4.5 to disable Two Factor Authentication in magento 2.4

> php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth Magento_TwoFactorAuth

Answer (score 1):

Change value of `Magento_TwoFactorAuth` to 0 in `app/etc/config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You need first disable

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush
```