# Magento 2.4.0 and 2FA auth

Tags: magento2.4

I did a clean installation of magento 2.4.0.
However after installation it asked me for enabling 2FA. With clicking on confirmation email link and selecting "google" for 2FA I'm getting following screen.

I tried to fix it via console (with bin/magento security:tfa:google:set-secret, see https://medium.com/adobetech/configuring-tfa-on-magento-2-4-0-admin-panel-with-google-authenticator-dbf8801da4c3), but I'm still getting the same screen after login. Cache clean and setup:di:compile didn't help.

Could you please anyone help? Thanks.

[image]

Kamil

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2.4 - Two factor authentication](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318674/magento-2-4-two-factor-authentication)

Answer (score -1):

You can disable that with this one :

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Disabling the feature is not a solution, if you need two factor auth.